# Check box for iPhone does not work on asp net mvc

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

check box for iPhone does not work, everything works on other devices, what could be the matter?

```
                <div>
                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkme" id="agree" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="" /> Я прочитал(а) <a>@Html.ActionLink("ПРАВИЛА", "rules", "home")</a> и согласен на обработку моих персональных данных.</p>
                    <input type="submit" id="continue" value="Регистрация" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#continue').prop('disabled', true);

  $('#agree').change(function() {

      $('#continue').prop('disabled', function(i, val) {
        return !val;
      })
  });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#agree').change(function() {
   if(this.checked)
       $("#continue").prop('disabled', false);
   else
       $("#continue").prop('disabled', true);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also Try this...

```
$('#agree').change(function() {
  if(this.checked)
   $("#continue").attr('disabled', false);
  else
   $("#continue").attr('disabled', true);        
 });
```